# wget --mirror not creating varnish cache

Tags: magento, wget, varnish, varnish-vcl

I have varnish cache installed on my server in port 80 with Apache as content server on port 8080. If I run wget --mirror example.com it should crawl through my entire website and create the varnish cache, right? It does not. For eg., by running wget --mirror example.com I can see in my output that it has run through example.com/abc.html. But when I go to example.com/abc.html from my browser, from my response headers I can see that it is returning Varnish MISS (and it also takes long time). However, if I go to the same url again via the browser this time the cache has been generated as I can see Varnish HIT in my response headers

Here is another interesting fact: If I run only run wget example.com/abc.html it will create the varnish cache! Another interesting fact: If I run wget --mirror example.com/abc.html it will create the varnish cache for abc.html but not further pages

So for some reason using --mirror example.com creates the varnish cache for first page but not further page.

I am using Magento if it makes any difference

I have tried:
    wget --mirror --no-http-keep-alive example.com
but it does not work

Here is my varnish vcl

```
# This is a basic VCL configuration file for PageCache powered by Varnish for Magento module.

# default backend definition.  Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "8080";
}

# admin backend with longer timeout values. Set this to the same IP & port as your default server.
backend admin {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "8080";
  .first_byte_timeout = 18000s;
  .between_bytes_timeout = 18000s;
}

# add your Magento server IP to allow purges from the backend
acl purge {
  "localhost";
  "127.0.0.1";
}


sub vcl_recv {
    if (client.ip ~ purge) {
      set req.hash_always_miss = true;
    }

if (req.restarts == 0) {
    if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
        req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
    } else {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
    }
}

if (req.request != "GET" &&
  req.request != "HEAD" &&
  req.request != "PUT" &&
  req.request != "POST" &&
  req.request != "TRACE" &&
  req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
  req.request != "DELETE" &&
  req.request != "PURGE") {
    /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
    return (pipe);
}

# purge request
if (req.request == "PURGE") {
    if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
        error 405 "Not allowed.";
    }
    ban("obj.http.X-Purge-Host ~ " + req.http.X-Purge-Host + " && obj.http.X-Purge-URL ~ " + req.http.X-Purge-Regex + " && obj.http.Content-Type ~ " + req.http.X-Purge-Content-Type);
    error 200 "Purged.";
}

# switch to admin backend configuration
if (req.http.cookie ~ "adminhtml=") {
    set req.backend = admin;
}

# we only deal with GET and HEAD by default    
if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
    return (pass);
}

# normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://[^/]+", "");

# static files are always cacheable. remove SSL flag and cookie
if (req.url ~ "^/(media|js|skin)/.*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|css|js|swf|ico)$") {
    unset req.http.Https;
    unset req.http.Cookie;
}

# not cacheable by default
if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Https) {
    return (pass);
}

# do not cache any page from
# - index files
# - ...
if (req.url ~ "^/(index)") {
    return (pass);
}

# as soon as we have a NO_CACHE cookie pass request
if (req.http.cookie ~ "NO_CACHE=") {
    return (pass);
}

# normalize Aceept-Encoding header
# http://varnish.projects.linpro.no/wiki/FAQ/Compression
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
    if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
        # No point in compressing these
        remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
    } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
    } else {
            # unkown algorithm
            remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # remove Google gclid parameters
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+$",""); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA"
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+&","?"); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA&foo=bar"
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"&gclid=[^&]+",""); # strips when QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA" or QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA&bar=baz"

    return (lookup);
}

# sub vcl_pipe {
#     # Note that only the first request to the backend will have
#     # X-Forwarded-For set.  If you use X-Forwarded-For and want to
#     # have it set for all requests, make sure to have:
#     # set bereq.http.connection = "close";
#     # here.  It is not set by default as it might break some broken web
#     # applications, like IIS with NTLM authentication.
#     return (pipe);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_pass {
#     return (pass);
# }
# 
sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.url);
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }
    if (!(req.url ~ "^/(media|js|skin)/.*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|css|js|swf|ico)$")) {
        call design_exception;
    }
    return (hash);
}
# 
# sub vcl_hit {
#     return (deliver);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_miss {
#     return (fetch);
# }

sub vcl_fetch {
    if (beresp.status == 500) {
       set beresp.saintmode = 10s;
       return (restart);
    }
    set beresp.grace = 5m;

    # add ban-lurker tags to object
    set beresp.http.X-Purge-URL = req.url;
    set beresp.http.X-Purge-Host = req.http.host;

    if (beresp.status == 200 || beresp.status == 301 || beresp.status == 404) {
        if (beresp.http.Content-Type ~ "text/html" || beresp.http.Content-Type ~ "text/xml") {
            if ((beresp.http.Set-Cookie ~ "NO_CACHE=") || (beresp.ttl < 1s)) {
                set beresp.ttl = 0s;
                return (hit_for_pass);
            }

            # marker for vcl_deliver to reset Age:
            set beresp.http.magicmarker = "1";

            # Don't cache cookies
            unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
            } else {
                # set default TTL value for static content
                set beresp.ttl = 4h;
            }
        return (deliver);
    }

    return (hit_for_pass);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # debug info
    if (resp.http.X-Cache-Debug) {
        if (obj.hits > 0) {
            set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
            set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;
        } else {
           set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
        }
        set resp.http.X-Cache-Expires = resp.http.Expires;
    } else {
        # remove Varnish/proxy header
        remove resp.http.X-Varnish;
        remove resp.http.Via;
        remove resp.http.Age;
        remove resp.http.X-Purge-URL;
        remove resp.http.X-Purge-Host;
    }

    if (resp.http.magicmarker) {
        # Remove the magic marker
        unset resp.http.magicmarker;

        set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
        set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
        set resp.http.Expires = "Mon, 31 Mar 2008 10:00:00 GMT";
        set resp.http.Age = "0";
    }
}

# sub vcl_error {
#     set obj.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
#     set obj.http.Retry-After = "5";
#     synthetic {"
# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
# <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
#  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
# <html>
#   <head>
#     <title>"} + obj.status + " " + obj.response + {"</title>
#   </head>
#   <body>
#     <h1>Error "} + obj.status + " " + obj.response + {"</h1>
#     <p>"} + obj.response + {"</p>
#     <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
#     <p>XID: "} + req.xid + {"</p>
#     <hr>
#     <p>Varnish cache server</p>
#   </body>
# </html>
# "};
#     return (deliver);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_init {
#   return (ok);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_fini {
#   return (ok);
# }

sub design_exception {
}
```

**Edit , Answer:**

I don't know whether adding the --no-cookies fixed it (don't know whether wget --mirror stores cookies and if it does then that would have fixed it) or whether adding the headers fixed it, but this works and creates the varnish cache which I can see via my browser:

```
wget --spider --recursive --no-cookies --header "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" --header "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3" --header "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8" --header "Cache-Control: max-age=0" --header "Connection: keep-alive" --header "Host: www.example.com" --header "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/10.04 Chromium/18.0.1025.168 Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19" www.example.com
```

**Second Edit, Related to previous answer. IMPORTANT**

Anyone using Magento, don't use my above solution. Because of --no-cookies, Magento ends up creating a new session file under var/session folder for every single request. This caused my session folder to be filled in with 250,000 files with every wget run of above command! This caused the folder to be full and none of my customers could actually add anything to their basket since Magento could not create any more session files for them. I am looking for more alternatives to my problem

Answer (score 1):

You should look into two points:

- All modern browsers send some `Accept-Encoding ~ 'gzip'` header, so cached entries will not be used if your spider doesn't use this one (a decent back-end generating gzipped responses adds a vary: `Accept-Encoding` header).
- Your back-end generates cookies for every cookie-less-user. Your script should keep its cookie but your cache rules should ignore cookies if they don't matter. However, if your responses include shopping-carts or other stuff (very user/state/cookie dependent) you can not cache this and you'll have to recreate this response every time. You can factor our the variable part with javascript/iframes, but you need to (re-)design your application to make it cacheable.